# Jsoup and formatting outputs

Tags: java, eclipse, web-scraping

/*I have been reading and learning about JSoup and web scraping(I am coding in eclipse IDE JAVA language), this is my first attempt at coming up with something that I am interested in.
I am essentially looking at creating a program that is like a textual based dashboard specific to what I feel is relevant for my interests,
contains information that I want, this start is live 
cricket scores (Go Aussies)*/

/*I will gladly accept any assistance with my issue, as it is now I have results coming through from the relevant page, however I wish to add Match Headings i.e Twenty 20 header then all relevant games return, then maybe a heading for Test Scores etc...These heading are available and I am accessing them via the temp4 variable, however when I add the code to the loop and print the result basically it doesn't line up correct due to the different lengths of match-section-head vs say innings-info-1. so I will get all the headings but will have the wrong games underneath them as well as it won't give me all the results that are on the page.*/

My Question is : How am I able to correctly use the match-section-head element which stores the headings of different competitions i.e (Twenty20 Competition, Test Matches, Women's ODI). Originally I was adding it to the loop however as there is much less match headings then there is actual matches it puts all my results out of order.

//I have included all code and as you can see with my comments what I was //trying to do with temp4 variable

Thanks in advance for any and all help, happy programming.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class CricketWebScrape
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Beginning of initial code connection to Website, add browser userAgent

        try
        {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/index.html?view=live").userAgent("Safari/11.0").get();

            //Elements object variables initialized and connecting to      Websites valid Elements via div.

            Elements temp = document.select("div.innings-info-1");
            Elements temp2 = document.select("div.innings-info-2");
            Elements temp3 = document.select("div.match-status");
            Elements temp4 = document.select("div.match-section-head");


            //Beginning of Loop that goes through all Elements listed above

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() && i < temp2.size() && i < temp3.size(); i ++)//&& temp4.size(): i ++
            {

                //Print statements to show valid data

                //System.out.println("**** " + temp4.get(i).text() + " ****");
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println(temp.get(i).text()
                        + " vs " + temp2.get(i).text());
                System.out.println(temp3.get(i).text());
                System.out.println(" ");

            }

        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How am I able to correctly use the match-section-head element which stores the headings of different cups (Twenty20 Competition, Test Matches, Women's ODI). Originally I was adding it to the loop however as there is much less match headings then there is actual matches it puts all my results out of order.